# Bottom bar doesn't show up in TableViewController iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have two TableViewControllers embedded in NavigationController, and I want to add bottom bar to the second table view controller. In the interface editor, I choose Opaque Tab Bar and it shows on the screen in the MainStoryboard, but when I build the app there is no bottom bar. Could you tell what is the reason why it doesn't show up and how to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboard is showing you **Simulated** metrics.

Add this to your `Cards` view controller class:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
}
```

That will show the ToolBar (the "bottom" bar) when the view is about to appear, and hide it when the view is about to disappear.